# Let $\{a_n\}$ be Cauchy and positive, then another Cauchy sequence$\{b_n\}$ is also positive if $a_n-b_n\rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

A Cauchy sequence $\{a_n\}$ is positive if there exists $B\in \mathbb{Q}$, $B>0$, and $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq N$ then $a_n\geq B$.

We want to show that if $\{a_n\}$ is postive and $a_n-b_n\rightarrow 0$, then the Cauchy sequence $\{b_n\}$ is also positive.

*This is what I have in mind:*

So for all $n\geq N_a$, we have
\begin{align*}
&a_n\geq B\\
\implies &  a_n-b_n\geq B-b_n
\end{align*}
Since $a_n-b_n\rightarrow 0$, for all $n\geq N_1$
\begin{align*}
\epsilon\geq a_n-b_n
\end{align*}
If I choose $N=\max(N_a,N_1)$, then forall $n\geq N$,
\begin{align*}
\epsilon\geq a_n-b_n \geq B-b_n.
\end{align*}
I can't invoke limit here because $b_n$ might converge to something $\not \in \mathbb{Q}$, even though $a_n-b_n$ converges to $0\in \mathbb{Q}.$

Credit to amsmath's hint:
Choose $\epsilon = \frac{B}{2}$, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{B}{2}\geq a_n-b_n \geq B-b_n \implies b_n-\frac{B}{2}\geq 0
\end{align*}

Comment: Looks good. You only have to choose $\varepsilon$ appropriately. In your text, you haven't said anything about it. What about choosing it to be $B/2$?

Comment: @amsmath, thanks for hint. But I still don't quite get it. Then I would get $0\geq B/2-b_n$.

Comment: @amsmath, Oh I get it now, then $b_n-B/2\geq 0 $, and $B/2$ is my $B_b$.

Comment: Exactly. You have $b_n\ge B/2$ for all $n\ge N$ and $B/2\in\mathbb Q$.